# Find is a business is open: MySQL hours calculation

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a list of business stored in a `locations` table, and stored in that table are hours the business opens and closes:

```
location
`mon_1_open`
`mon_1_closed`
`tue_1_open`
`tue_1_closed`
`wed_1_open`
`wed_1_closed`
```

ect...

I store the times in full hours and minutes, so say a business is open from 9:00AM to 5:30PM on monday.. `mon_1_open` = '900' AND `mon_1_closed` = '1730'.

I can't seem to figure out a way to find the day of week and output if the business is else open or closed based on the time of day.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This does not necessarily answer your question, but it may in the long run.

Your database scheme seems flawed. It definitely is not normalized. I would address that before it becomes a big issue, as you have noticed that it makes it hard to locate certain businesses hours. Here is a draft scheme that might be better suiting.

```
TABLE: locations
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    name VARCHAR(50) 

TABLE: location_hours
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    location_id INT  -  Foreign Key references locations table
    day CHAR(3) - (examples: mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun)
    hours VARCHAR(4) - (could also be int)
```

Then to get todays date, this can be done in MySQL with [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) `%a`, an example query:

```
SELECT locations.name, location_hours.hours 
FROM locations 
    JOIN location_hours ON locations.id = location_hours.location_id 
WHERE location_hours.day = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a') 
    AND location.name = 'Someway Business'
ORDER BY location_hours.hour
```

You *should* not need an open / close given that the the `ORDER BY` knows that `0900 < 1430` since it is a `VARCHAR` (although `INT` should know how to sort it as well), but your code when adding businesses will either need to update this record or you will need another field `active` to signify if that row should be used in the query. Just remember to use 24 hour time. Again this is a mock up, I just created it on the spot so it probably could use some improvements, but that would be better then doing a hack like you would have to with your current code.

**UPDATE**

Addressing the comment about finding if it is open or close:

Just use the PHP `date` function and call `date('Hi')` this will pull out the current time in 24-hour time, then you just do a simple if statement to see if it is between that, if it is, it is opened.

IE:

```
$sql = "SELECT locations.name, location_hours.hours 
FROM locations 
    JOIN location_hours ON locations.id = location_hours.location_id 
WHERE location_hours.day = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a') 
    AND location.name = 'Someway Business'
ORDER BY location_hours.hour";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL Failed with Error: " . mysql_error());

$times = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (empty($times['open'])) {
        $times['open'] = $row['hours'];
    }else {
        $times['closed'] = $row['hours'];
    }
}

$currentTime = date('Hi');

if ($times['open'] <= $currentTime 
        && $times['closed'] > $currentTime) {
    echo "Open";
}else {
    echo "Closed";
}
```

Given that my logic is correct. Again, this is just pseudo code an example of usage. Given I just wrote it up on the spot. The above assumes you are only querying one business at a time.

Comment: I like your concept, and wish to use it. But I'm getting no output at all. Maybe it is at the date_format? I don't under stand how that works.

Comment: If you have access to the MySQL Console, run `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%a', NOW());`  It will output todays date in abbreviated form, all which is explained at the manual.

Comment: I think I see how it work now, but what would you recommend for PHP in order to figure out if the business is "Yes we are open" or "Sorry we are closed". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but how would I find $timeOpenFromDB and $timeCloseFromDB since with the current code, it is only grabbing the closest time...

Comment: The current code should return two rows. I will update the code with the psuedo procedure attached.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But what would be the best way to log to sets of times a business is open in a day? For example: 9:00AM-11:30AM AND 12:30PM - 5:00PM. Would this be possible to implement in the current database and code structure?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dayOfWeek = strtolower(date('D'));

$query = '
    SELECT
        location,
        '.$dayOfWeek.'_1_open <= '.date('Gi').' AND
        '.$dayOfWeek.'_1_closed >= '.date('Gi').' as is_open';
```

That should work.

However, you really should use a proper time datatype for the open/closed columns.